# Php form not working

Tags: php, forms, input

So I have this PHP form with basic name, email and message inputs, however I can't get it to work! I've tried putting ID and NAME tags for each of my form elements but it won't work.

Here's the php snippet

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $to = "xxx@example.com.br"; 
    $subject = "Success!";
    $name_field = $_POST['nome'];
    $email_field = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['mensagem'];
    $body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n $check_msg\n Message:\n $message\n";
    echo "Your form was sent!";
    mail($to, $subject, $body);

} else {
    echo "Ouch.";
}
?>
```

and the form

```
<form action="../php/send.php" method="post">
<label>Name:</label><input id="name" name="name" /><br />
<label>Email:</label><input id="email" name="email" /><br />
<label>Message:</label>
<textarea id="message" name="message" ></textarea><br />

<button type="submit" id="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Any error messages or does the message just not send?

Comment: in html this is as 'name' = > $name_field = $_POST['nome']; and this is as 'message' => $message = $_POST['mensagem'];

Correct your code first, check if it works and ask again!

Comment: is it linux or windows server. replace your `$body` `\n` with `PHP_EOL` and `$_POST['mensagem'];` shouldn't it be `$_POST['message']`

Comment: @kjy112: `\n` will be parsed and handled equally on both Windows and Linux servers. Real purpose of `PHP_EOL` is different - dealing with files without worrying about the platform. Also, `PHP_EOL` does not work with regular expressions, which is a cons. Just my two cents :)

Comment: @Andrejs on windows server the return is `\r\n` so the email won't send if the newline char is `\n`

Comment: @kjy112: I've got no problems with both platforms so far. Perhaps you're right - I'm not 100% sure, and don't want to spend time on that :)

Comment: @Andrejs well maybe it's just me but i had a huge problem with sending mail on windows platform a few months back because of it.  However, sometimes messages without `\n`, `\r\n` or PHP_EOL still able to send out which is really strange.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't defined a 'submit' field (there's no `name="submit"` in the form), so your `if()` test is failing.

A better method to check for POST is

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   ...
}
```

That entry is always present, and is far more reliable than checking for a particular field.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to replace this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

with something obvious, like:

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
```

Also, there are couple of mistakes:
This:

```
$name_field = $_POST['nome'];
$email_field = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['mensagem'];
```

Should be:

```
$name_field = $_POST['name'];
$email_field = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
```

Also, you need to check that `mail()` returns `true`. Change:

```
echo "Your form was sent!";
mail($to, $subject, $body);
```

To:

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
    echo "Your form was sent!";
} else {
    echo "mail() returned error! Your form was not sent!";
}
```

If you are sure that `mail()` is actually being executed without any errors, but mails are still not being sent out / reached the recipient, check the server logs, perhaps you need to configure php (normally not) or `sendmail`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$name_field = $_POST['name'];` within the POST checking statement, use `$name_field = $_REQUEST['name'];`  The `$_REQUEST` will always grab the `name=` of an input field of the form you submitted from.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $to = "xxx@xxx.com.br"; 
    $subject = "Success!";
    $name_field = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $email_field = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'];
    $body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n $check_msg\n Message:\n $message\n";
    echo "Your form was sent!";
    mail($to, $subject, $body);
    // now do something else like adding thank you 

} else {
    echo <<< END
<form action="../php/send.php" method="post">
<label>Name:</label><input id="name" name="name" /><br />
<label>Email:</label><input id="email" name="email" /><br />
<label>Message:</label>
<textarea id="message" name="message" ></textarea><br />

<button type="submit" id="submit"></button>
</form>

END;
}

?>
```

That should work

Answer (score 0):

It is just a DOM error just change your input field name="myname" or anything else it'll solve your problem.

```
<form action="../php/send.php" method="post">
<label>Name:</label><input id="name" name="my_name" /><br />
<label>Email:</label><input id="email" name="email" /><br />
<label>Message:</label>
<textarea id="message" name="message" ></textarea><br />

<button type="submit" id="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no name attribute attached to your submit button, the PHP code you have written listens for POST data name "submit".
  Change this:

```
<form action="../php/send.php" method="post">
<label>Name:</label><input id="name" name="name" /><br />
<label>Email:</label><input id="email" name="email" /><br />
<label>Message:</label>
<textarea id="message" name="message" ></textarea><br />

<button type="submit" id="submit"></button> <!-- Add a name attribute -->
</form>
```

To this:

```
<form action="../php/send.php" method="post">
<label>Name:</label><input id="name" name="name" /><br />
<label>Email:</label><input id="email" name="email" /><br />
<label>Message:</label>
<textarea id="message" name="message" ></textarea><br />

<button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"></button> <!-- Name attribute added -->
</form>
```

Comment: The PHP script will then detect that this POST data has been sent.